# Cannot find file in NodeJS on Windows if name contains undercore and dashes

Tags: javascript, node.js, encoding, escaping, fs

I'm trying to read a file on Windows 7, filename looks like:

```
SOME_SOMEELSE_2018-10-11T00-38-55
```

My code:

```
let ff = path.resolve(__dirname, 'SOME_SOMEELSE_2018-10-11T00-38-55.html');
fs.readFileSync(ff, 'UTF8');
```

As soon as I change filename to something like `123.html` it works right off, and I'm able to read file content.

What I tried:
Encoded `_` and `-` to Unicode (`\u005F` and `\u2212` accordingly), 
checked for about hundred times the path to file, 
normalized path, resolved path, normalize + resolve at the same time,
hardcoded absolute path excluding filename,
replaced backward slashes to forward ones when path is ready,
but nothing seems to work.

Output:

```
ENOENT: no such file or directory, open 'D:\work\rep\SOME_SOMEELSE_2018-10-11T00-37-36.html'
```

Output for simplified filename (no special characters of any kind, say `test.html`) with the same snippet in the same location returns file content.

Any ideas?

Comment: What version of Node.js are you using?

Comment: @Trott it’s 8.11.3

Comment: I am unable to reproduce this. Using a simplified line of code: `console.log(require('fs').readFileSync(require('path').resolve(__dirname, 'SOME_SOMEELSE_2018-10-11T00-38-55.html'), 'UTF8'))` outputs the contents of the file on Windows 10. It could theoretically be something to do with the ancient version of Windows you're running, but I highly doubt it. Try copying and pasting the name of the file from Explorer; you might have some non-printable characters in there.

Answer (score 0):

Remove the leading `/` from the second argument of `path.resolve()` so that it will be a relative path rather than an absolute path.

```
let ff = path.resolve(__dirname, 'SOME_SOMEELSE_2018-10-11T00-37-36.html');
fs.readFileSync(ff, 'UTF8');
```

It works when you change it to `123.html` because that is a relative path.

More explanation: The problem isn't `_` or `-`. The problem is that the second argument is an absolute path, and that means that the first argument gets ignored. From [the docs](https://nodejs.org/docs/latest/api/path.html#path_path_resolve_paths):

> The given sequence of paths is processed from right to left, with each subsequent path prepended until an absolute path is constructed. For instance, given the sequence of path segments: /foo, /bar, baz, calling path.resolve('/foo', '/bar', 'baz') would return /bar/baz.

Comment: When I print my resulting path (ff) it points directly to the file, which I can open by copy-paste it into windows explorer.

Comment: I mean, path when printed in node error is like
_Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, open ‘D:\work\rep\SOME_SOMEELSE_2018-10-11T00-37-36.html’_, 
same file with filename _test.html_ in the same location is being read nicely.

Comment: Are you sure that error isn't coming from some other line or something?

Comment: I mean...  https://gist.github.com/Trott/61c883d70e2c3cd587566198a53bc485